# Create A shortcut command in command line

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, command-prompt

When you try and compile a C++ program on a command line, you have to type out:

`g++ -Wall -std=c++XX <filename>`

Is there a way to create a command, say `compile`, that basically acts as a shorter way to say `g++ -Wall -std=c++XX`?

So, instead of saying `g++ -Wall -std=c++XX file.cpp`, I can just say `compile file.cpp`, and it would do the same thing?

EDIT: This is for Windows 10

Comment: Yes. They are called build systems. The most used on linux is make and cross platform is cmake. There are others

Comment: and you can always write a simple bash or equivalent or python script

Comment: Or batch (`.bat`) scripts on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

For your question, that is what make files are for. It is a little bit hard for me to explain it all here so just go to the following link: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/
After you have your makeFile include all your header files in the include section and your cpp files in the source section. When you compile it just type make into the terminal or command prompt depending on your system.

Comment: Links rot, and when the link in this answer rots the answer becomes pretty much useless.

Comment: Why don't you try explaining the whole make file process here if you are so smart then, which is limited to 500 words.

Comment: Answers aren't limited to 500 words, and a simple makefile can be described in whatever size limit answers do have. My general recommendation is to summarize the topic so that the information can be rediscovered after the link rots, but in this case I'd suggest skipping makefiles entirely and offering up a simple batch file.

Comment: Batch files are not portable, it is going to bite him in the back when he goes to the industry if he doesn't know how to use a make file, as many programmers use UNIX based operating systems and although MakeFiles are more complex, they are also more portable.

Comment: Consider the time costs of trying to learn two languages at the same time, C++ and Make, when all you want to do is reduce the amount of typing needed while learning C++. The effort's not worth it yet. Make doesn't really start getting useful until you've got larger programs, and if you've got that, I'd recommend learning cmake instead of make.

Comment: Note: If you're trying to get the downvote removed, you'll need to appeal to someone else.

Comment: Also if you are learning C++ you should be prepared to spend time on it. If you are not willing to spend the time stick with java bruh. Also C++ is really powerful only when you understand it to the core, I do not think trying to reduce the time to learn C++ so you have a worse understanding of the language is a good idea.

Comment: You know what I mean: Destructors, copy constructors, Dynamic Memory Allocation, Templates, Operator Overloading, Assignment Operators, Move Constructors, and much more. The beauty of C++ is it's complexity, if you do not like complexity stick with Java.....

Comment: Spent ten years on C++ already. They keep adding stuff to it. Did a bit of Java between 96 and 2005, but I'm mostly a C guy. The only complexity you get in C is the complexity you bring in.